# Compiling a simple hello world servlet into a .war for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm doing some simple benchmarks, and I want to create a simple servlet that displays hello world, I have that part:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{ 
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException,IOException{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
  pw.println("<html>");
  pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
  pw.println("<body>");
  pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
  pw.println("</body></html>");
  }
}
```

Now I installed with the default installation of tomcat, in the folder:

.../libexec/webapps/ROOT

I believe I have to drop a war file, is it possible to compile the above java class into a .war file w/o and editor using the command line only?

Answer (score 5):

A war file is simply a zip file, so with an appropriate directory structure and web.xml, you can create one with command line tools.

The web.xml should contain at a minimum a way to direct your URL to your servlet.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http:/java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This web.xml should be in a folder named `WEB-INF` inside your war, and the compiled java class file should be in `WEB-INF/classes`

The war file should be dropped in the `webapps` directory, not the `ROOT` directory.

Tomcat will find your war file, and unzip it.

If it was named "hello.war", the default context name would be "hello", and accessed at `http://yourhost/hello/`

Comment: can I just drop that file above into tomcat or I have to use a .war file?  what is the command line to convert it to war then?

Comment: @Blankman Use the `jar` command. And no, you can't just drop the web.xml, you need the rest of your app's resources (servlet class files, JSP, etc.)

Comment: ok so I create the web.xml, and put the java class in web-inf/classes as described above, use the jar command to create hello.war, drop the hello.war into the webapps folder, and fire up tomcat and hit /hello/ and it should work?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. `WEB-INF` does need to be in capitals though.

Comment: Just as a side comment, by default Tomcat listens for HTTP connections on port 8080, in that case the URL would be: `http://yourhost:8080/hello`

Comment: The default URL for `hello.war` would be rather `http://yourhost:8080/hello`, as Tomcat binds to port 8080 by default.